# Adding a alarm to a todo list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a to-do list that will split up word when put ‘ , ‘ and separate them into different items on the list I also have a alarm that you can set to go off on a certain time I'm just trying to make the alarm be attached to each item on the list on the page. And its not visible until you have put some import in.  any help is appreciated.

```js
var notesArray = Array();

function add_element_to_array() {
  let splits = document.getElementById("text1").value.split(',');

  // loop through each item splits and push it to notesArray
  for (var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
    notesArray.push(splits[i]);
  }

  /*
  // you can also do this using concat:
  notesArray = notesArray.concat(splits);
  
  // or using the new spread syntax
  notesArray.push(...splits);
  */

  document.getElementById("text1").value = "";
}


function display_array() {
  let e = "<hr/>";
  for (var y = 0; y < notesArray.length; y++) {
    e +=  + y + " - " + notesArray[y] +"<br />" + "<br />" ;
  }
   document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = e ;

}


//Alert

var alarmSound = new Audio();
alarmSound.src = 'alarm.mp3';
var alarmTimer;

function setAlarm(button) {
  var ms = document.getElementById('alarmTime').valueAsNumber;
  if(isNaN(ms)) {
    alert('Invalid Date');
    return;
  }

  var alarm = new Date(ms);
  var alarmTime = new Date(alarm.getUTCFullYear(), alarm.getUTCMonth(), alarm.getUTCDate(),  alarm.getUTCHours(), alarm.getUTCMinutes(), alarm.getUTCSeconds());
  
  var differenceInMs = alarmTime.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();

  if(differenceInMs < 0) {
    alert('Specified time is already passed');
    return;
  }

  alarmTimer = setTimeout(initAlarm, differenceInMs);
  button.innerText = 'Cancel Alarm';
  button.setAttribute('onclick', 'cancelAlarm(this);');
};

function cancelAlarm(button) {
  clearTimeout(alarmTimer);
  button.innerText = 'Set Alarm';
  button.setAttribute('onclick', 'setAlarm(this);')
};

function initAlarm() {
  alarmSound.play();
  document.getElementById('alarmOptions').style.display = '';
};

function stopAlarm() {
  alarmSound.pause();
  alarmSound.currentTime = 0;
  document.getElementById('alarmOptions').style.display = 'none';
  cancelAlarm(document.getElementById('alarmButton'));
};

function snooze() {
  stopAlarm();
  alarmTimer = setTimeout(initAlarm, 300000); // 5 * 60 * 1000 = 5 Minutes
};
```

```css
html{
    background-color:rgba(0, 89, 255, 0.514);
    user-select:none;
    position:relative;
    left: 25px;
    top: -20px;
    font-size:x-large

}

.Quest{
    font-family: 'Cookie', cursive;
}

#text1{
    outline: none;
    border:none;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    
   
}

.h1{
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
   
}
input{
    outline: none;
    border:none;
}

#button1{
cursor: pointer;
font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
}


#button2{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
}

html {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  #Result{
    font-family: 'Do Hyeon', sans-serif;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&display=swap');
        </style>
        <style>
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&display=swap');
            </style>
            <style>
                @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cookie&display=swap');
                </style>
                <style>
                    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+2&display=swap');
                    </style>
                  <style>
                    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Do+Hyeon&display=swap');
                    </style>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>try</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='index.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class='Quest'>Quest</h1>
    <center>
        <h1 class="h1">Enter</h1>
        <input type="text" id="text1"></input>
<input  type="button" id="button1" value="Add" onclick="add_element_to_array();"></input>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Display" onclick="display_array();"></input>
<div  id="Result"></div>  
 


<!--alerts -->
<div class = 'Alert'>
<div class='alertContaner'>
    <input id="alarmTime" type="datetime-local">
    <button id="alarmButton" onclick="setAlarm(this);">Set Alarm</button>

    <div id="alarmOptions" style="display: none;">
        <button onclick="snooze();">Snooze 5 minutes</button>
        <button onclick="stopAlarm();">Stop Alarm</button>
    </div>
    
</div>
</div>
</center>
<!--alerts -->



    <script src='index.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, "alarm be attached to each item on the list on the page" have you try anything to achieve this? In code, I don't see anything specific to this that you might have tried.

Comment: I have tried a bunch of different things but I ended up getting rid of it cause nothing was working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires you to create DOM for each to-do item added. I am not sure what have you tried till now but the following is one way of doing it.

The first is to change the function `display-array()` to create the DOM on runtime.

```
function display_array() {
  // For each to-do create the above structure using DOM manipulation.

  // 1. HTML element for todo
  // 2. Input for date and time.
  // 3. Button to set/cancel the alarm. Attach the click event to set alarm and pass unique id for this todo.
  // 4. Button to snooze. Attach the click event to snooze and pass unique id for this todo.
  // 6. Button to stop. Attach the click event to stop and pass unique id for this todo.
}
```

Second, keep a record of each todo and its respective timer in the array using the `alarmTimer` map. You will use this to clear the timer for respective todos. For a new todo-item create a new object for existing update the timer.

```
let alarmTimer = [{
   todo_index: I,
   todo_desc: notesArray[i],
   timer: window.setTimeout(function () {
     initAlarm(i);
   }, differenceInMs)
}];
```

Also, you will need an array `event_handlers` to hold the last attached event for the `alarmButton` to switch between set and cancel alarm buttons.

[Check this code for reference and details.](https://codesandbox.io/s/workspace-js-4ddep?file=/index.html)

Comment: Darshna Rekha thanks for taking your time to help me out. Really appreciated it.